# Deploy ASP.NET Boilerplate Core & Angular to Microsoft Azure

Tags: angular, web-deployment, aspnetboilerplate

I would want to deploy ASP.NET Boilerplate Core & Angular to Microsoft Azure. The current version of ASP.NET Boilerplate contains two solutions (one for the backend and one for the frontend) so i need to deploy it to two different AppServices and a SQL database.
Here is what i tried:

Publish the back-end application:

- create an Web App + SQL App Service.
- configure the Web.Host/appsettings.production.json as following:

  ```
  "App": {
      "ServerRootAddress": "https://myapp-backend.azurewebsites.net/",
      "ClientRootAddress": "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/",
      "CorsOrigins": "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/"
  }
  ```
- publish the application to Azure using Visual Studio
- i am able to see the swager for the API when browsing to https://myapp-backend.azurewebsites.net/

Publish Angular

- create a new simple Web App for the Angular Client.
- run ng build -prod
- copy the web.config. It looks like this:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <clear />
          <!-- ignore static files -->
          <rule name="AngularJS Conditions" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(app/.*|css/.*|fonts/.*|images/.*|js/.*|node_modules/.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
            <action type="None" />
          </rule>    
          <!-- check if its root url and navigate to default page -->
          <rule name="Index Request" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^$" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/home" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
          </rule>    
          <!--remaining all other url's point to index.html file -->
          <rule name="AngularJS Wildcard" enabled="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/app" />
          </rule>    
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>`
  ```

This is the `json` configuration:

- Configure the `angular/dist/assets/appconfig.json` like following:

  ```
  {  
    "remoteServiceBaseUrl": "https://myapp-backend.azurewebsites.net",  
    "appBaseUrl": "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net"  
  }
  ```
- Send the publish files from dist to wwww folder to Azure via FTP
- When browsing to https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/ i see an error in the console application indicating: "Unexpected token < " like in the image below:

[image]

If i type [enter link description here](https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/app/home) i am getting this error message:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I assume it is probably related to the Web.config and the way the routing are set in the Angular application but i at this moment i am lost. Could you help?

Comment: Have you seen [Step by step publish to Azure Angular](https://aspnetzero.com/Documents/Step-by-step-publish-to-azure-angular)?

Comment: Thank you, yes, i have tried it and i wasn't able to make it work. I also used the Web.config from the Angular directory.

Answer (score 1):

the link of official doc is changed to [Deployment Angular - Publish Azure](https://docs.aspnetzero.com/en/aspnet-core-angular/latest/Deployment-Angular-Publish-Azure).

But there is also another interesting way of publishing www/dist folder to **static site** and as **storage account**. Without worrying about asp.net we.configs and blocked json files.

- [Step by step guide publish to azure static web site(storage account)](https://docs.aspnetzero.com/en/aspnet-core-angular/latest/Step-by-step-publish-to-azure-angular-staticsite)

**Why use Azure Storage**

> AngularUI is a static website, therefore it can be deployed in Azure
> storage which provides features specifically designed for static
> websites. such as Custom Domains, and SSL. Also; using Azure Storage
> is **much cheaper** than deploying an app Service on Azure.